# Mount a volume on cronjob in Openshift

Tags: cron, openshift, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have Jenkins POD that mounts a pv with a pvc. 
Now I want to create a cronjob that use the same pvc in order to do some log rotation on jenkins build.
How can I access to Jenkins PVC from cronjob in order to do some batch procedures on PV?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access to Jenkins PVC from cronjob in order to do some batch procedures on PV?

Personally I think you can consider the following ways to share Jenkins PVC with CronJob pods.

- Share PV which is created as ReadWriteMany with two PVC, such as Jenkins PVC and CrontJob PVC. Refer [Sharing an NFS mount across two persistent volume claims](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html)
   for more details.
- OR mount Jenkins PVC when CronJob Pod start up after stopping the Jenkins Pod.
  It's required to stop Jenkins Pod before mount the PVC with Cronjob pod.

I hope it help you.